# Apache/php sending wrong content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

I have an apache server (Apache/2.2.9 (UNIX) PHP/5.2.6) and a local development environment. I am making a ajax call from `gestion_mandats.php` like this:

```
<li onclick="changePage(event,2)">
  <a href="../templates/pagination_mandat_template.php?pagination_page=2&amp;totalpage=128" title="Page suivante">Page suivante</a>
</li>
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: encodeURI("../templates/pagination_mandat_template.php?pagination_page=1&totalpage=<?= $total_pages.$filterStr;?>"),
    success: function(result){
      $("#target-content").html(result);
    },
    cache: false
  });

  $("#reinitBtn").click(function(e){
    $("#filterForm").find("input[type=text], textarea, select").val("");
  });
});

function changePage(e,pageNum){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#target-content").html('Chargement...');

  $.ajax({
    url: encodeURI("../templates/pagination_mandat_template.php?pagination_page=" + pageNum + "&totalpage=<?= $total_pages.$filterStr;?>"),
    success: function(result){
      $("#target-content").html(result);
    },
    cache: false
  });
}
```

On my local environment everything is working well. However on my server, 3 times out of 4, instead of getting `pagination_mandat_template.php` the AJAX call is retrieving `gestion_mandats.php`

In my network panel on chrome is see a 200 [GET] request on `pagination_mandat_template.php` and on my apache logs i see:

```
10.101.4.28 - - [28/Mar/2018:16:05:39 +0200] "GET XXXXXXXX/templates/pagination_mandat_template.php?pagination_page=1&totalpage=141&_=1522245939922 HTTP/1.1" 200 10982
```

I don't have any .htaccess file and no redirections on my PHP, I am just building an HTML table.

At this point I am stuck, I don't have any ideas on how to correct this.

Comment: What event are you running the JS code under? It sounds like whatever event it is is refreshing the current page as you make the AJAX request which is leading to the behaviour you're seeing

Comment: I'm using this chunk of code under `$(document).ready(function() {` and a function called on onclick event

Comment: Right, but on click of...?

Comment: `<li onclick="changePage(event,2)">` and the function start like this :  `function changePage(e,pageNum){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#target-content").html('Chargement...');

         $.ajax({...`

Comment: Is the AJAX request the only logic in the `changePage()` function? It would really help if you could add a more complete sample of your HTML and JS.

Comment: Here is the [javascript](https://pastebin.com/3JW1agv7) and the html is like this : `<li onclick="changePage(event,2)"><a href="../templates/pagination_mandat_template.php?pagination_page=2&amp;totalpage=128" title="Page suivante">Page suivante</a></li>`

Comment: But don't you think it's comming from server-side instead ?

Comment: The `a` element inside the `li` is causing a page redirect. No, I don't think it's a server side problem.

Comment: But the problem even occurs on the document ready event, and not on my development environment  (same browsers btw)

Answer (score 0):

I would organize the Ajax code to be in only one function.

Then call that same function on page load AND on click.

Here is the HTML needed:

```
<li id="next">
  Page suivante
</li>
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function changePage(pageNum){
    $("#target-content").html('Chargement...');

    $.ajax({
      url: encodeURI("../templates/pagination_mandat_template.php?pagination_page=" + pageNum + "&totalpage=<?= $total_pages.$filterStr;?>"),
      success: function(result){
        $("#target-content").html(result);
      },
      cache: false
    });
  }

  // On page load, get page #1
  changePage(1);

  // A page counter.
  var actual_page = 1;

  // On li click
  $("#next").on("click",function(){
    // Increment the page counter.
    actual_page++;

    // Get that page.
    changePage(actual_page);
  });

});
```

There should not be any content mixup with this.

If you place the JS in an external .js file, clear the browser's cache to make sure this latest code is executed.

Comment: Thank you for the code improvement, this is a lot better like that. but my problem is definitely server side. In the network tab, is see a 200 request on pagination_mandat_template.php but when i check the server's answer i see the page gestion_mandats.php. So the server is giving me a wrong answer

Comment: If you have a response from `gestion_mandats.php`, it comes from somewhere else than the code you posted. That's for sure. Now I can't tell. The server cannot give you a "wrong answer". It just does what you ask. ;)